# What do I call a smaller section of a cave?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

I mean, in the context analogous to when there's a side road leading off a main road.

I look for a term that replaces such a 'side road' when I'm speaking about caves.

Is 'branch' a correct term or do I need to use something like 'passage' or 'section' and be more specific instead?

Comment: "Side cavern" is common, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good to me. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I would read this: http://vancouverisland.com/things-to-do-and-see/recreation/vancouver-island-bc-islands/caving/

Comment: @Lambie Thank you, reading it straight away and bookmarked it for the future use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what kind of cave it is.  Branch-work caves are most common and they are called “branches”, “passages”, or “tributaries”.

Also, we generally say “what do I call X” rather than “how do I”. It is proper to say “how do I say “xxx” “.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. Tributaries are some sort of 'water' caves, did I understand correctly?

Comment: Many caves were formed by flows of water. So even if the cave is dry now, they may use the riverine term “tributary”.